# Connected to OS X Server Yosemite VPN not seeing Network Server in Finder

Tags: vpn, osx-yosemite, osx-server

I can get the VPN connected and I am given a proper network IP address but I am not seeing the Server in the Network area of finder.

This is the last line from `ifconfig` in terminal:

`inet 10.168.1.240 --> 10.168.1.254 netmask 0xff000000`

I want the VPN experience to be as if I am on my home network.

My Routing Tables as requested:

Inside the network:

```
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            10.168.1.1         UGSc           64        0     en1
10.168.1/24        link#4             UCS             5        0     en1
10.168.1.1/32      link#4             UCS             1        0     en1
10.168.1.1         18:1b:eb:31:ca:4f  UHLWIir        66      128     en1   1200
10.168.1.4/32      link#4             UCS             0        0     en1
10.168.1.10        0:11:d9:35:7c:17   UHLWI           0       38     en1   1177
10.168.1.11        d0:e7:82:c7:5e:8f  UHLWIi          3      163     en1   1180
10.168.1.254       10:dd:b1:99:72:56  UHLWIi          1      209     en1    996
10.168.1.255       ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0        1     en1
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              0     7665     lo0
127.94.0.1         127.94.0.1         UH              1     6507     lo0
169.254            link#4             UCS             0        0     en1
```

Outside the network with a VPN to inside the network:

```
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.43.1       UGSc           24        0     en1
default            link#8             UCSI            0        0    ppp0
10                 ppp0               USc             1        0    ppp0
72.84.100.145      192.168.43.1       UGHS            5       76     en1
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              0     7690     lo0
127.94.0.1         127.94.0.1         UH              1     6526     lo0
169.254            link#4             UCS             0        0     en1
192.168.43         link#4             UCS             1        0     en1
192.168.43.1/32    link#4             UCS             1        0     en1
192.168.43.1       2:1a:11:f3:a8:c1   UHLWIir        27      163     en1   1179
192.168.43.124/32  link#4             UCS             0        0     en1
192.168.43.255     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0        1     en1
```

Comment: Are you trying to map a network drive to a server after you setup a VPN tunnel?

Comment: No I am not. I just want my server to appear in Network as it does on my home network.

Comment: Have a look at the bottom answer to this post (http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080307092123215). Have you tried tracert or nslookup?

Comment: Thanks @rastaBob that looks promising. Will give it a go and report back.

Comment: Look like that deals with Windows Servers and not Apple Servers.

Comment: The point about NetBIOS being localised to the broadcast domain (not traversing the VPN) is really OS independent. To fix it however you will need to find someone who can tell you how to configure the DNS search suffixes &/or WINS correctly on osx.

Comment: Please post your routing table.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae posted the tables when in and outside of network.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You cannot.

Long answer: If you use VPN on the L2 level and you create a bridge, then it should work just like you would be on your home network.

Using L2 level network causes overhear and it's usually not what you want. (Usually one of the things not wanted is broadcast and multicast traffic when using VPN and that's the reason why on your common L3 level VPN you cannot use "bounjour/avahi/netbios" to locate your services) This means that you are assing an ip from you home network just as you'd be home.

See these links for more info: [Similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/445680/how-can-bonjour-be-setup-to-function-over-a-vpn-connection-using-mac-os-x-moun), [VPN links and bonjour](http://www.wedebugyou.com/2013/01/how-to-use-bonjour-over-vpn/), [Workaround](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080626194901370)